# Trouble creating active directory users with Java

Tags: java, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I've got a windows server 2008R2 with an active directory.
I want to create a Java program, what allows a 08/15-user to add new users to this AD.

I have found an [example][1] in the oracle forums and modified it for my AD.:

```
package model;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.ModificationItem;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.StartTlsRequest;
import javax.naming.ldap.StartTlsResponse;

public class NewUser2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    String adminName = "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=Dom215-01,DC=local";
    String adminPassword = "g18";
    String userName = "CN=Foo Bar,OU=Schueler,DC=Dom215-01,DC=local";
    String groupName = "OU=Schueler,DC=Dom215-01,DC=local";

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

    // set security credentials, note using simple cleartext authentication
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, adminName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, adminPassword);

    // connect to my domain controller
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://10.18.215.112");

    try {

        // Create the initial directory context
        LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

        // Create attributes to be associated with the new user
        Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes(true);

        attrs.put("objectClass", "Schueler");
        attrs.put("samAccountName", "FooBar");
        attrs.put("cn", "Foo Bar");

        // These are some optional (but useful) attributes
        attrs.put("givenName", "Foo");
        attrs.put("sn", "Bar");
        attrs.put("displayName", "Foo Bar");
        attrs.put("description", "Test Subject");

    /*  
        attrs.put("userPrincipalName", "asdf@asdf.com");
        attrs.put("mail", "sdaf@sdaf.com");
        attrs.put("telephoneNumber", "999 123 4567");
    */

        // some useful constants from lmaccess.h
        int UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 0x0002;
        int UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD = 0x0020;
        int UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE = 0x0040;
        int UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT = 0x0200;
        int UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = 0x10000;
        int UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 0x800000;

        attrs.put(
                "userAccountControl",
                Integer.toString(UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT + UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD
                        + UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED + UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE));

        // Create the context
        Context result = ctx.createSubcontext(userName, attrs);
        System.out.println("Created disabled account for: " + userName);

        StartTlsResponse tls = (StartTlsResponse) ctx
                .extendedOperation(new StartTlsRequest());
        tls.negotiate();

        ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[2];

        String newQuotedPassword = "\"Password2000\"";
        byte[] newUnicodePassword = newQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");

        mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,
                new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", newUnicodePassword));
        mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,
                new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl",
                        Integer.toString(UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT
                                + UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED)));

        ctx.modifyAttributes(userName, mods);
        System.out.println("Set password & updated userccountControl");

        try {
            ModificationItem member[] = new ModificationItem[1];
            member[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE,
                    new BasicAttribute("member", userName));

            ctx.modifyAttributes(groupName, member);
            System.out.println("Added user to group: " + groupName);

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem adding user to group: " + e);
        }

        tls.close();
        ctx.close();

        System.out.println("Successfully created User: " + userName);

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem creating object: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem creating object: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Everything looks Ok so far, but when it tries to create the result object in line 76 it crashes with an `NoSuchAttributeException` and LDAP error code 16 (no such attribute).
I've tried various modifications in the username string and the attributes, but nothing helped.

Does anyone have an idea why this error occurs?

Comment: Glad you gotit working. IMO your choice of test inputs are really unprofessional...

Comment: Well... You're right. I had a bad day. I'll edit that

Comment: Yeah..and can you post your solution as an answer, don't edit it into the question. I have rolled it back so you can do this. You can find it in the history here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8176001/revisions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok. Sorry, I'm new to this forum.
Anyway... Here the solution again :

```
package model;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

public class NewUser {

    private static final String DOMAIN_NAME = "Dom215-01";
    private static final String DOMAIN_ROOT = "DC=Dom215-01,DC=local";
    private static final String DOMAIN_URL = "ldap://10.18.215.112:389";
    private static final String ADMIN_NAME = "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=Dom215-01,DC=local";
    private static final String ADMIN_PASS = "g18";

    private String userName, firstName, lastName, password, organisationUnit;
    private LdapContext context;

    public NewUser(String userName, String firstName, String lastName,
                    String password, String organisationUnit) {

        this.userName = userName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
        this.organisationUnit = organisationUnit;

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

        // set security credentials, note using simple cleartext authentication
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ADMIN_NAME);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ADMIN_PASS);

        // connect to my domain controller
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, DOMAIN_URL);

        try {
            this.context = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem creating object: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public boolean addUser() throws NamingException {

        // Create a container set of attributes
        Attributes container = new BasicAttributes();

        // Create the objectclass to add
        Attribute objClasses = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
        objClasses.add("top");
        objClasses.add("person");
        objClasses.add("organizationalPerson");
        objClasses.add("user");

        // Assign the username, first name, and last name
        String cnValue = new StringBuffer(firstName).append(" ").append(lastName).toString();
        Attribute cn = new BasicAttribute("cn", cnValue);
        Attribute sAMAccountName = new BasicAttribute("sAMAccountName", userName);
        Attribute principalName = new BasicAttribute("userPrincipalName", userName
                + "@" + DOMAIN_NAME);
        Attribute givenName = new BasicAttribute("givenName", firstName);
        Attribute sn = new BasicAttribute("sn", lastName);
        Attribute uid = new BasicAttribute("uid", userName);

        // Add password
        Attribute userPassword = new BasicAttribute("userpassword", password);

        // Add these to the container
        container.put(objClasses);
        container.put(sAMAccountName);
        container.put(principalName);
        container.put(cn);
        container.put(sn);
        container.put(givenName);
        container.put(uid);
        container.put(userPassword);

        // Create the entry
        try {
            context.createSubcontext(getUserDN(cnValue, organisationUnit), container);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static String getUserDN(String aUsername, String aOU) {
        return "cn=" + aUsername + ",ou=" + aOU + "," + DOMAIN_ROOT;
    }
}
```